# Bootstrap dropdown password recovery submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building bootstrap site and I'm stuck with the Forgot Password option in the Login menu.

When you click the Log In button, which opens a dropdown form, and then click the Forget password link, I want an entirely new form with inputs for password reset (ex. email, username etc.) and new button with different action for password reset. I want the form to appear the same place of the log in form (it should switch).

What's the best way to this?

Here's the snipped i'm using: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3kNkX

Thanks in adanvce.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to have a form hidden in the same element the login form is in and have the **Forgot Password** link hide the login form and display the recover password form.

Answer (score 0):

Put the contents of the forgot password form in an HTML file and load that into the little box that holds the login form. I used `.slideInRight` as the selector for the login form, but it's probably better if you give that box a unique ID and use that as the selector instead.

```
$('.forgot-password').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.slideInRight').load('/forgot-password-partial.html');
});
```